# Laravel form validation for returning dropdown values

Tags: javascript, validation, laravel-5

When a validation fails, I want my dropdowns to have previously selected values in it.My drop down list is populated from javascript. Validation does not validate this dropdown box values.

Drop down list in my view

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label align="right" for="ItemID" class="control-label col-xs-2">Item :</label>
      <select class="col-md-5 input-sm" name="itemID" id="ItemID" >
         <option>  </option>             
      </select>
</div>
```

My java script for loading values

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#Year').on('click',function(e){
        var year= e.target.value;
          $.getJSON('/xxxxx/xxx?year=' + year, function(data){

          $('#ItemID').empty();
           $.each(data,function(index, courses){
             $('#ItemID').append('<option value="'+courses[0].ID+'">'+courses[0].Code+'</option>');
           });
        }); 
      });
 });
```

I tried following for getting previously selected values using [this tutorial](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/form-validation-with-old-input?page=1).

```
<select class="form-control" name="item" id="item">
<option disabled selected>Velg...</option>
@foreach ($items as $item)
    <option value="{{ $item->name }}" @if (old('item') == $item->name) selected="selected" @endif>{{ $item->name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

**PS :** When I use this coding, it returns the ID value, not the code in dropdown box.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label align="right" for="ActivityItemsID" class="control-label col-xs-2">Activity : </label>
       <select class="col-md-5 input-sm" name="ActivityItemsID" id="ActivityItemsID" >
          <option value="{{Input::old('ActivityItemsID')}}" > {{Input::old('ActivityItemsID')}}  </option>
              <option value=" "> </option>
       </select>
  </div>
```

But It doesn't work. How to get previosly selected values for the form?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue you have is that you're loading in options you want selected via AJAX after the page has loaded.

There are many other ways to do this better but to reuse as much of your code as possible I'd just push a script to your footer with some dynamic values straight from your blade template so you can access old() in your ajax callback.

```
@push('scripts')
$(document).ready(function(){

    function getItems(year) {
        $.getJSON('/xxxxx/xxx?year=' + year, function(data){
            $('#ItemID').empty();
            $.each(data,function(index, courses){

                $('<option value="'+courses[0].ID+'">'+courses[0].Code+'</option>').appendTo('#ItemID');

                // If the page has errors we use the old input to check for a match and select the element after the ajax request has run
                @if( count($errors) > 0)
                if( courses[0].ID == {{ old('ActivityItemsID') }} ) {
                    $('#ItemID').val( courses[0].ID );
                }
                @else
           });
        });
    }

    // Manually populate the dropdown if a year is selected, if this is a select box you should change on('click' to on('change'
    $('#Year').on('click',function(e){
        getItems(e.target.value);
    });

    // If the page loaded with errors, use the year from the input to prepopulate the dropdown
    @if (count($errors) > 0)
    getItems( {{ old('year')  }} );
    @endif
});
@endpush
```

This code makes a lot of assumptions, you'll have to ensure field names are correct etc. Generally if I'm using a lot of ajax to load dynamic form data I'll handle validation on the client side with Laravel validation just as a fallback if someone disables Javascript, that way you can run your post-validation code while retaining the current state of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I just set the old value in the select box itself.

```
  <select id="subcategories" data-old="{{old('subcategories')}}" name="subcategories" class="form-control">
      <option value="0">Choose Sub-Category</option>
  </select>
```

Then after loading the elements of the dropdown dynamically i just check the old value in data-old to see if it exists and then set the dropdown accordingly.